# Customise Django Admin page redirect after editing object

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a specific requirement to customise where the user is redirected to after making changes to an object in the Django Admin in *certain cases*:

The expected behaviour:

1. On `Object A` change form, click on 'Change' on related Inline `Object B`
2. Make changes to `Object B` and hit 'Save'
3. User is redirected to the original `Object A` change form (and not back to the list view of all `Object B`'s, as is default.)

*and*

1. On `Object B` list page click on an `Object B`
2. Make changes to `Object B` and hit 'Save'
3. User redirected to the `Object B` list page (and not any associated `Object A` page, as would be customised in the case above.)

That is to say the redirect is different depending on where the user has come from. What is the best way to customise this behaviour?